# msi execution trigger/switch

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I have an agent that should be installed on each computer in a specific OU and updated if there is a new msi package for installation, im skipping whole msi deployment and error handling because everything works fine but i have one bug that buggers me;)

I have a problem with one tihng: **if msi installs without any problems, the script should not run again on the computer.** Since I cannot check the installer version (sometimes the same version of the msi package contains a different configuration) either instalation date cannot be considered.

I thought that after the successful installation (exitcode 0) I will create a text file in "\windows\temp\myagent\ "with the name corresponding to the given update, eg "JUL2022.txt"

im chcecking file with:

```
if(Test-Path -Path $updateTrigger -PathType Leaf)
       {
         exit
       }
    else
       {
        do stuff
       }
```

It works just fine for almost every machine in OU but on few of them installation repeats itself almost every time with boot despite "JUL2022.txt" is present. I don't really know why this is happening, and I have no idea how else I can tell if the desired installation has already taken place.

Comment: It depends on how `$updateTrigger` is defined.

Comment: its just a path
 $updateTrigger = 'C:\Windows\Temp\myAgent\JUL2022.txt'

Comment: Do you get any error messages, when you execute your script manually on a machine, that performs the installation over and over again?

Comment: scritp started locally returns no errors, when it gets to the point where im checking if txt exist in temp it stops ( as it should)